# How do I modify the logic of the buttons in this d3 visualization?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 visualization ([codepen here](http://codepen.io/laissezpasser/pen/OXkgAk)) for which I'm trying to modify the logic of the selector buttons.
They currently read:

- Everyone
- Male (all)
- Female (all)
- Maldivian Males
- Maldivian Females
- Foreign Males
- Foreign Females

What I'd like to do is group

- Everyone
- Maldivian
- Foreigner

and also group

- Male
- Female

...so that there are no more than five buttons, total.

For example, the graph would default, as it currently does, to "everyone." If, from the default, I clicked "Female," it would give me the data stream "female_all." If I made a further selection, e.g. "Maldivian," I would get the data stream "Female_Maldivian" (which would obviously be mutually exclusive of any selections for "Foreigner" and or "Male").

How do I achieve this?

Some seemingly relevant code:

```
<div id="buttons">
<div class="button current" data-val="all">Everyone</div>
<div class="button" data-val="female_all">Females</div>
<div class="button" data-val="male_all" style="margin-right:0">Males</div>
<div class="button" data-val="female_maldivian">Female Maldivians</div>
<div class="button" data-val="male_maldivian" style="margin-right">Male Maldivians</div>
<div class="button" data-val="female_foreign">Female Foreigners</div>
<div class="button" data-val="male_foreign" style="margin-right">Male Foreigners</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

In advance, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Are you able to change the structure of your source data?

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways would have been to alter data. But if that's not the option I tweaked your code to understand multiple data-values on HTML button. As such you can group them to entertain multiple column of your data file and it will compile a sum... such as:

```
<div class="button" data-val="female_maldivian,male_maldivian">Maldivians</div>
```

would give u a sum of females and male maldivians. So you can mix and match any fields from your data file and plot a chart. Check 'area_older' & 'area_younger' functions for the changes.

& check out the working fiddle at : https://jsfiddle.net/9rcfgmfb/

Comment: Thanks, but the females and males have different weights within "Everyone", "Maldivian", and "Foreigner", so summing them isn't an option. Ideally looking for a solution that doesn't break the mouseover function, either.

Comment: So there was an issue with mouseover, I had to make adjustments for my code changes that I ddnt notice: here is the updated fiddle that doesnt break: https://jsfiddle.net/9rcfgmfb/1/ . Also I ddnt realize these numbers are averages, so made changes for that too. Rest, am not able to understand, what exactly are you trying to do? I guess you should be able to map any data calculations to this approach.